# Can a c\c++ function have compound type in definition

Tags: c++, c, function, types, declaration

Would you please help me with this question;

I am wondering what are all the types that a c\c++ function can be defined in. For example in a simplest way a function is defined as void, int, double, char, string etc. Then W might define a function of String[] type also. Would you please explain me what are the "all" possible variants that a function can be defined.

BR
Vard

Comment: Pick your language: C doesn't have a `String` type. C++ does, but it's called `std::string`. And in C++, you probably won't pass that as a `std::string[]` array.

Answer (score 1):

There are an infinite number of possible function signatures.  You can have a function return a built-in type or a type you've defined yourself.

Comment: Although `String[]` appears to indicate an array, and that won't be possible as a return type - `vector<string>` does however work.

Comment: That's true, but you can also put the string array into a struct or class wrapper, and it will be returnable.

Comment: I see. Thus if we are to write a program that will identify all the functions' definitions and list it, how are we going to read the code, so we can distinguish a function definition from anything else? For example to check if there is curly braces succeeded by function name and brackets (which should not be a reserved word in that particular language) succeeded by type of return, which could be any valid name that could be defined for class or name of primitive types. Any explanation?

Comment: @Vard - well certainly it's possible.  That's what a a compiler does, after all.  All of the parsing rules are in the language spec if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the return type of C++ function can be any valid datatype either build - in or User-defined.

Answer (score 0):

The definition you put in front of the function name is the type of value to be returned.  Thus, a `void` function does not return any value, an `int` function must return an `int` value, and a `user_def_type` function must return a `user_def_type` value.  The complete signature of a function is defined by its return value type, its name, and a list of parameters with each parameter declared with its type.  So, you have zillions of ways to define the function.

Comment: Technically, the signature of non-template functions does not include the return type.

Comment: And for C++, the class is part of the signature of member functions.